# How to manage JavaScript(.js) files in web page if js files are bigger in numbers?

Tags: javascript, html

I have more that 15 (.js) files in my web page. I need to know is there any other and efficient way to manage java script(.js) files in an HTML or jsp page other than putting all .js files in script tag ?

Comment: Yes you should combine them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different ways to do this, First one as mentioned is to combine them.. Another way is to user server side code to combine  them during execution time.

**SIMPLE PHP EXAMPLE:** myscripts.php

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
    echo file_get_contents("scripts/script1.js");
    echo file_get_contents("scripts/script2.js");
    echo file_get_contents("scripts/script3.js");
    echo file_get_contents("scripts/script4.js");
?>
```

By using the above method, you can still manage your scripts easily and have them appear as only one script in your site / page.. Simple use the above with something like

```
<script src="myscripts.php"></script>
```

If you do not have a server side language (which generally would mean this is not a hosted page), then you are very limited with options. So that would be the first one i would suggest.

Also,, forgot the one that google use.. Use a single script that includes the others by adding a script tag to the body of your page..

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to optimize your website if you have too many js files.

1. Combining scripts into a single file
2. Minify scripts: this helps reducing file size
3. Using a script loader like [Headjs](http://headjs.com/)

Ofcourse there are other approaches to solving this issue based on the specific scenario. I've just named a few which are common.